SignalR with Blazor, unable to refresh component from another page
I got stuck with this problem for multiple days and have been reading the implementation on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-8.0     of course it couldn't help me.
My problem was not able to update the component from the code below when using Clients.Caller or Clients.Client. I was able to update the component using Clients.All but it updated all connected clients for my visitors which I didn't want.
I only wanted to update status for the same visitor/user only and it didn't work for me.
If anyone here know how to solve this problem, please let me know. Thank you.

using DocZ.Data;
using DocZ.Helpers;
using DocZ.Models.Security;
using DocZ.Services.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorWebAssemblySignalRApp.Server.Hubs
{
    public class BannerMyUsageHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly ILogger<BannerMyUsageHub> _logger;
        private readonly IDatabaseService _databaseService;
        public BannerMyUsageHub(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory, IDatabaseService databaseService, ILogger<BannerMyUsageHub> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _databaseService = databaseService;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Location to receive SignalR request from client app or within the backend
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task MyUsageMessageTouserName(string userName)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) == false)
            {
                //Get total record from database
                int totalMyUsage = await _databaseService.BannerMyUsageCountPending(userName);
                string messageToViewer = "";
                if (totalMyUsage > 0)
                {
                    messageToViewer = $"You have {totalMyUsage} open chart{UtilityMethods.Pluralization(totalMyUsage)}.";
                }

                //Blazor didn't refresh the header.
                await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", messageToViewer);
                //Blazor couldn't load other browser tab from the say user.
                //await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", messageToViewer);

                //Can't use this becuase it would update all visitors.
                //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", messageToViewer);
                //Didn't work at all... await Clients.User(userName).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", messageToViewer);

            }
        }
    }
}





Hi Ai Vay, from the the code you shared,  I found a mistake in your code, why you are using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client; package in your hub class?  We should remove it if you don't know that.

And another suggestion is we should enable logging feature to check happened when you are invoking the Clients.Caller and Clients.Client, according to my experience, the error should related to the wrong data format, maybe you can get the error message about System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value  could not be converted to System.String....

Try to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject to convert the data.
await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageToViewer));
//await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageToViewer));

Then you can receive the data like below.
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(receive_messageToViewer);

